# How can I compare a slug url with the current address?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have this `if` for a static page:

```
{% if request.get_full_path == "billing/address/" %}
    test
{% endif %}
```

how can I replace `billing/address/` with the path getting from here:

`path('billing/address/<slug:address_slug>/', views.addressChange, name='edit-address')`

Thanks guys

Comment: the `request.get_full_path()` will give you something like this, **`/billing/address/my-address-slug/`**

Comment: Apart from that, I don't understand your exact requirement :(

Comment: I'm trying to make a tab active based on the address, this is an example:             `<a href="{% url 'settings:security-settings' %}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action {% if 'security' in request.resolver_match.url_name %} active {% endif %}"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i> Security</a>`

Comment: So I want when users visit the address tab with which ever slug, to make the billing tab active

Comment: So, you want to do an **`in`** operation....right? to check whether the entered url contain the `billing/address/` path

Comment: Yep, that would work

Comment: I've added an answer, check it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, the Python's **`in`** operator will do the magic :)

```
{% if "billing/address/" in request.get_full_path %}
    test
{% endif %}
```